# EF6 How to specify directory for add-migration?

Tags: entity-framework-6

On VS2019, C#, EF6, using the Package Manager Console, I am trying to specify the `-OutputDir` for the `Add-Migration` command according to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) but it always writes to the root of the project. If I remove the `-OutputDir` param, it will write inside the \Migrations folder but I prefer to be inside `\Migrations\MySubFolder`

```
PM> add-migration -name CreateInitialTables -OutputDir \Migrations\MySubFolder -context MyDbContext
```

Comment: The path is relative from where you run the command. Perhaps you should be using `Migrations\MySubFolder` or `.\Migrations\MySubFolder`?

Comment: You are asking about EF6, but links to EF Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for [`Add-Migration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#add-migration):

> -OutputDir <String>: The directory use to output the files. **Paths are relative to the target project directory**. Defaults to "Migrations".

Because the path is relative, you need to specify the path without the leading slash, or use `.\` to indicate the current directory. For example:

```
add-migration -name CreateInitialTables -OutputDir .\Migrations\MySubFolder -context MyDbContext
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using the `dotnet ef migrations` command, you can use the `--output-dir` argument to do this.

From `dotnet ef migrations add --help`:

```
...
Options:
  -o|--output-dir <PATH>                 The directory to put files in. Paths are relative 
                                         to the project directory. Defaults to "Migrations".
...
```

For example:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context MyContext --output-dir Migrations\MyContext
```